# using linq on TableRowCollection

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have an AspTable with a small number of rows.  I want to run a linq Where() on the collection to find one and remove it.

mytable.Rows is of type TableRowCollection
mytable.Rows.AsQueryable() says it returns a Linq.Queryable but intellisense on this does not give me my Linq operators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
myTable.Rows.Cast<TableRow>()
```

The problem is that `TableRowCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<T>` - and it's the latter that LINQ to Objects works with, primarily. The above will create an `IEnumerable<TableRow>` which will basically cast each item in turn.

Comment: I wish you had included more information. I'm new to LINQ and stuck in the same boat, but can't do a LINQ conditional count on myTable.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Count(n => n.ID.CompareTo("myRowId") == 0);

Comment: What do you mean by "can't"? It sounds like you should ask a new question. (It's not clear why you're using `CompareTo` rather than just `Count(n => n.ID == "myRowId")` either.)

Comment: Not sure what was happening before because now it debugs without errors. int rowcount = myTable.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Count(n => n.ID == "myRowId"); works perfectly fine. As for the CompareTo, I've just been taught to not use == for string comparison. Due to switching between languages, it's been for the better but == works fine for this case.